# Is there a way to make Quality Tools settings in PhpStorm global?

Tags: php, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

The `PHP | Quality Tools` settings in PhpStorm settings are not global, but I would want them to be. The desired effect would be that when opening a (new) project, the settings will be the same across all instances.

Any tips as to how this could be achieved are more than welcome :)

Comment: Not exactly global. Just pre-configured. `File | New Projects Setup | Settings for New Projects` -- affects only future new projects obviously (has no effect on any existing ones).

Comment: I had seen this option, but was hoping there would be an easy way to sync it to existing projects. I will go for this one, as it is probably the most straightforward solution at this moment.

Comment: I have tested the option you mentioned, but that does not apply the changes on projects that are newly checked out from version control. Do you perhaps know a way to apply the configuration when checking out a new project from VCS?

Comment: Should work for them as well TBH (I see no obvious reasons why not). The only thing I can think of: maybe that project already has `.idea` in it and the IDE will not overwrite such settings then. Anyway -- try other way around: make a new empty project, add VCS info and then do the checkout (instead of creating a new project straight from VCS).